# Re deploy Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, recreate, redeploy

I made a mistake and I delete a virtual machine I need, This VM has a OS DISK in vhd file that I keep in the storage, is there any way to re-deploy the virtual machine using this OS DISK?,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where **exactly** is the OS disk? Is this an ARM (Azure Resource Manager) or "Classic" VM?

Comment: please refer : https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2018/10/create-an-azure-virtual-machine-from-an-existing-managed-disk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with these steps

**1)**  Navigate to your **Managed Disk** and click it.
[image]

**2)**   Click on **Create VM**
[image]

**3)**  **Create a virtual machine blade** showing. You will see under Image your Managed Disk. Just fill in the blade as you would when creating a new VM.

[image]